# “Read More” description is not hidden by default, but only after clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem where I want the “READ MORE” button to show the description once the user clicks on it, by default the description should be hidden, after user click on “READ MORE” it should show it. But sadly it shows the description at default and after I click the “READ MORE” and “READ LESS” button, then it hides the description.

This is my code and my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc5kpw8q/):

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var dots1 = document.getElementById("dots1");
  var moreText1 = document.getElementById("more1");
  var btnText1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

  if (dots1.style.display === "none") {
    dots1.style.display = "inline";
    btnText1.innerHTML = "READ MORE";
    moreText1.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots1.style.display = "none";
    btnText1.innerHTML = "READ LESS";
    moreText1.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <!--Title-->
  <h4 class="card-title">Johor Rugby Carnival Meets 96 teams at EduCity</h4>
  <!--Text-->
  <p class="card-text"> <span id="dots1"></span><span id="more1">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction1()" id="myBtn1" class="btn btn2">READ MORE</button>
</div>
```

I expect the description would be hidden at default and only shown after the user clicks the “READ MORE” button.

Comment: It’s bad practice to check for CSS properties directly. Assign a CSS class instead and check for it (e.g. `dots1.classList.has("hidden")`). In this case, you could use the [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the default style on the `more1` span, and any others you want this to apply to, to be `display:none`

```
<span id="more1" style="display:none">
```

```js
 function myFunction1() {
    var dots1 = document.getElementById("dots1");
    var moreText1 = document.getElementById("more1");
    var btnText1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

    if (dots1.style.display === "none") {
      dots1.style.display = "inline";
      btnText1.innerHTML = "READ MORE";
      moreText1.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dots1.style.display = "none";
      btnText1.innerHTML = "READ LESS";
      moreText1.style.display = "inline";
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <!--Title-->
  <h4 class="card-title">Johor Rugny Carnival Meets 96 teams at EduCity</h4>
  <!--Text-->
  <p class="card-text"> <span id="dots1"></span><span id="more1" style="display:none">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction1()" id="myBtn1" class="btn btn2">READ MORE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No worries! If this helped please mark this as the accepted answer to help others know that this was the solution! :)

Comment: I will do it after 10 minutes cause it is restricted to mark your answer below 10 minutes by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Different Solution With Jquery With Animation If you want then you can do it easily

Before Doing it you have to import Jquery **link**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {
        var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less';
        $(".show_hide").text(txt);
        $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jquery link -->

<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read More</a>
<div class="content">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</div>
```

You Can Edit or Preview Code [Here On JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd1kmhzp/1/)